# JS regular expression is not working

Tags: javascript, regex

Why is this regexp not workin in js ???

```
var nameRegExp = /^[\p{L}]{2,14}$/;
```

i mean

```
nameRegExp.test('fsdglsdjg');   ===>   false

nameRegExp.test('двыопыов'); ===> false
```

in java `\p{L}` means 'letter of any language'. Is there anything like this in JS?

I cant use any of libraries or smtng like this. Only natibe js

Comment: `\S` is any non-whitespace character in regex

Comment: tnx guys, but i need 'only letter' . No digits and other

Comment: In Chrome, use `/^\p{L}{2,14}$/u`. It won't work in JS environments that are not ECMAScript 2018 compliant.

Comment: Wiktor. Spent a lot of time on that problem. TNX A LOT.

Comment: If you decide to use the solution, make sure your site requires Chrome. Cheers.

Comment: Find below a link which helps you build a RegEx with any language letters: 
https://regular-expressions.mobi/unicode.html?wlr=1